# Corrupted XML file due hard reboot in UWP c#

Tags: c#, xml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

In my code there's an XML file that I use to get information from it (variables), in different methods, but when there's a street light issue (something I can't control) which makes my device hard reboot the **XML file gets corrupted**, I'm trying with this, but it **throws an exception in this line

```
using (fsFileStream = 
        new FileStream( musicLibraryPath...
```

help will be really appreciated. I leave my code below:

```
public async void fileExist(string fileName)
{
        

 try
{
    //Creates "file.xml".
    StorageFile newBlankDocument =
                await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFileAsync(blankFile, CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
}
catch (Exception)
{
   
}

try
{
    //Creates "configFile.xml".
    StorageFile newDocument = 
        await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
    //Gets the file
    StorageFile fileDocument = 
        await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync(fileName);

    var musicLibrary = await StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(KnownLibraryId.Music);
    String musicLibraryPath = musicLibrary.SaveFolder.Path;

    using (fsFileStream = 
        new FileStream( musicLibraryPath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 1024, FileOptions.WriteThrough))
    {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;

        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fsFileStream, settings))
        {
            //Create all the XML document fields.
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("Config");
            writer.WriteStartElement("General");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("name", "DATA");
            writer.WriteStartElement("Local");
            writer.WriteElementString("something1", "");
            writer.WriteElementString("something2", "");
            writer.WriteElementString("something3", "");

            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Dispose();
            showReferenceWarning();
            timerReferenceWarning.Start();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //The file already exists and doesn't need to be created again.
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> but it throws an exception in this line " using (fsFileStream = new FileStream( musicLibraryPath... "

Windows Store apps run sandboxed and have very limited access to the file system. For the most part, they can directly access only their install folder and their application data folder. You cannot use the `Path` directly. If you want write data to xml file, you could `await fileDocument.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)`.

```
public async void fileExist(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        //Creates "file.xml".
        StorageFile newBlankDocument = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFileAsync("file.xml", CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
    try
    {
        //Creates "configFile.xml".
        StorageFile newDocument = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
        //Gets the file
        StorageFile fileDocument = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync(fileName);

        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            using (var fsFileStream = await fileDocument.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                settings.Indent = true;
                settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;

                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fsFileStream.AsStreamForWrite(), settings))
                {
                    //Create all the XML document fields.
                    writer.WriteStartDocument();
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Config");
                    writer.WriteStartElement("General");
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("name", "DATA");
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Local");
                    writer.WriteElementString("something1", "");
                    writer.WriteElementString("something2", "");
                    writer.WriteElementString("something3", "");
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteEndDocument();
                    writer.Flush();
                    writer.Dispose();
                }
            }
        });

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {            
        //The file already exist and doesn´t need to be created again.
    }

}
```

Please note, if you has used music library you need to  declare capabilities in the app manifest. For more you could refer [Capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appxmanifestschema/element-capability).

Comment: Yeah, i already gave the musicLibrary capability in app manifest.
I have saved files in there and there was no problem with it, the thing is that i necessarily need the " FileOptions.WriteThrough" option, cause it protects the file in case of a hard reboot. 

Also your code gives the following argument: cannot convert from Windows.Storage.Stream.IRandomAccessStream to System.IO.Stream
Here: `using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fsFileStream,settings))
                        {
                            //Create and write all the XML document fields to 
    the file.`

Comment: You can not access `MusicLibrary` with path, so I use file `OpenAsync` method, and use `AsStreamForWrite()` to convert `IRandomAccessStream` to `Stream`.